# Picker not firing to selecteditem

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am having an issue with selecting value in my picker.
I have implemeted View Model and  I can display the options but once i select the item, the selected option doesnt get fired and the returnig value is null.  I have I notify in baseviewmodel,  can you help, please

```
  class CategoriesViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public CategoriesViewModel()
        {
            _mainSection = FillMainSection();
        }
        private List<MainSection> _mainSection = new List<MainSection>();
        private MainSection _selectedMainSection;
        public List<MainSection> MainSection
        {
            get => _mainSection;
            set => SetProperty(ref _mainSection, value);
        }

        public MainSection SelectedMainSection
        {
            get => _selectedMainSection;
            set
            {
                
                switch (_selectedMainSection.Position)
                {
                    case 0:
                        _selectedMainSection.Value = 0;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        _selectedMainSection.Value = 1;
                        break;
                }
                SetProperty(ref _selectedMainSection, value);
            }
        }

        public List<MainSection> FillMainSection()
        {
            var newListMainSection = new List<MainSection>()
            {
                new MainSection()
                {
                    Position = 0,
                    Text = Resources.AppResources.LabelPetsCategory,
                    Value = 0
                },
                new MainSection()
                {
                    Position = 1,
                    Text = Resources.AppResources.LabelLostAndFound,
                    Value = 1
                },
              
            };

            return newListMainSection;
        }
    }
}

Xaml 
    <Picker
                                        x:Name="SectionPicker"
                                        Title="{x:Static resources:AppResources.LabelSection}"
                                        Grid.Row="2"
                                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Text}"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding MainSection}"
                                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMainSection, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                        
                                        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make a test with your code. Here is running gif.

[image]

First of all I change the binding mode to `Mode=TwoWay` for `SelectedItem`, then I add a Label to display the select item from `Picker`.

```
  <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Picker
                 x:Name="SectionPicker"
                 Title="title"
                 Grid.Row="2"
                 ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Text}"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding MainSection}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMainSection, Mode=TwoWay}"              
                                        />
        <Label Text="test" TextColor="OrangeRed" />
        <Label Text="{Binding MainSectionText}" TextColor="OrangeRed" />
    </StackLayout>
```

Here is my `CategoriesViewModel.cs`, please notice you `SelectedMainSection`, `Position` and `Value` have same values, why you need to use `switch` to set it again, if you use MVVM, you use `SetProperty`, it will update for model, you do not need to update the properties again for this model.

```
   public class CategoriesViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private List<MainSection> _mainSection;
        private MainSection _selectedMainSection;
        public CategoriesViewModel()
        {
            _mainSection = FillMainSection();
          //  _selectedMainSection = new MainSection();
        }
       
        public List<MainSection> MainSection
        {
            get => _mainSection;
            set => SetProperty(ref _mainSection, value);
        }

      
        public MainSection SelectedMainSection
        {
            get => _selectedMainSection;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedMainSection, value);
                MainSectionText = "select item" + _selectedMainSection.Value.ToString();
              //  switch (_selectedMainSection.Position)
               // {
              //      case 0:
              //          _selectedMainSection.Value = 0;
              //          break;
              //      case 1:
              //          _selectedMainSection.Value = 1;
              //          break;
             //   }
               
               
            }
        }
        private string _mainSectionText;
        public string MainSectionText
        {
            get
            {
                return _mainSectionText;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _mainSectionText, value);
            }
        }
        public List<MainSection> FillMainSection()
        {
            var newListMainSection = new List<MainSection>()
            {
                new MainSection()
                {
                    Position = 0,
                    Text = "LabelPetsCategory",
                    Value = 0
                },
                new MainSection()
                {
                    Position = 1,
                    Text = "LabelLostAndFound",
                    Value = 1
                },

            };

            return newListMainSection;
        }
    }

    public class MainSection
    {
        public MainSection()
        {
        }

        public int Position { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

}
```